# REST WebServices in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

I need to develop a Rest Webservice, Where can I find tutorial or complete sample code to build REST WebServices in C#. Please help me with sample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [WCF Rest Starter Kit](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20REST&ProjectName=aspnet) is probably your best starting point.

Also, Aaron Skonnard of Pluralsight did a great screencast series on the WCF REST Starter kit - check it out at the [Pluralsight screencast page](http://www.pluralsight.com/main/screencasts/default.aspx) (click on the REST tag in the tag cloud).

For general information on WCF, including the REST bits of it, check out the [MSDN WCF Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/wcf).

Hope that helps!

Marc

Answer (score 4):

[How to: Create a Basic WCF REST Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178.aspx)

[REST Enabled Service in WCF Tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/RESTEnabledService05122009034907AM/RESTEnabledService.aspx)